# Use of a4j:commandbutton vs h:commandbutton to present-new-pages in richfaces

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I have completely substituted the h:commandButton with a4j:commandLink in my application for reasons not relevant to this issue. Since then I am seeing flaky peculiar side-effects in IE8 such as select menus that are losing focus and select items that cannot be selected.

Does anyone think that it is a bad idea to use a4j:commandButton instead of h:commandButton for some reason? Does anyone have any prior experience on this?

Any answer is welcome.

Comment: Have a look here: http://community.jboss.org/wiki/CommonAjaxRequestsProblems#navigation

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue when using `a4j:commandLink` for navigation in Firefox 3.5, as described here

[JSF problem with FireFox 3.5 caching, wyciwyg:// prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984801/jsf-problem-with-firefox-3-5-caching-wyciwyg-prefix)